# Dynamic Connection String

Tags: asp.net

Good Day,

I have two connection strings defined in my web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDb" connectionString="CONNECTION-STRING1"/>
    <add name="LaptopDb" connectionString="CONNECTION-STRING2" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I am working on my desktop, I want to use the connection string "AppDb".  When I am working on my laptop, I want to use the connection string "LaptopDb".  I don't want to comment out the line on the connection string everytime I work on a different machine.

I know that I can programatically do this.  I'm just trying to figure out the best way.

Something like:

```
if (machineName == desktop)
     use AppDb
else
     use LaptopDb
```

but I don't like this approach.  Is there something else I can test on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another couple of approaches you could consider:

- You can use the `configSource` attribute to read the configuration for that element from another file, the contents of which can be different on each machine:

  http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/04/26/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files.aspx
- Or you can use different build configurations and [use XDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx) to transform the `web.config` file.

Answer (score 1):

Really not too hard to do -- the trick is to use the `System.Environment.MachineName` to drive which string to pick and to get your connection string from a static property:

```
public static string ConnectionStringName
{
    get
    {
        var customConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Environment.MachineName] != null;
        var connectionStringName = customConnection ? Environment.MachineName : "DefaultDb";
        return connectionStringName;
    }
}
```